# Migrating Etherpad DB from MySQL to Mongodb

Tags: mysql, mongodb, migration, etherpad

I want to migrate the DB behind our Etherpad server from MySQL to Mongodb.

Are there any known scripts to do this? If not, are there any showstoppers for writing a script myself?

Comment: How can there be a script - no one but you knows what your schema is in MySQL or in MongoDB.

Comment: Everyone who uses Etherpad knows the schema. :)

Comment: I hoped that someone already did the migration.

Answer (score 3):

1. Dump your current store table to an SQL file using mysqldump or another sql dump tool.
2. Set mongo as the db of choice in Etherpad's settings.json file, restart Etherpad.
3. Read the SQL file into the database [using this script](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/blob/develop/bin/importSqlFile.js)

And in commands that's..

```
mysqldump -uroot -pwhatever store > etherpad.sql
vi settings.json (editing your database to use your mongodb)
/etc/init.d/etherpad-lite restart
node bin/importSqFile.js etherpad.sql
```

Should do it.

Comment: Too early - the script is not working for me. It says "Start importing 63 keys...", and "done" after that but I belive that there should be some more keys in the db. :) In Mongo, a new collection named "store" is created, but that's all. Any hints?

Comment: Add some debug console.warns in there to find out why it's not inserting the data :)